# Writing data from python list?

Tags: python

I have three list A,B and C. I want to write the contents of the list to the file like this:
A[1]
B[1]
C[1]

A[2]
B[2]
C[2]
.
.
.

Comment: Do you know for sure that these lists will have same number of elements? You probably want to serialize or save objects as CSV?

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, some code snippet will help.  I also think that @wheaties answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the lengths of all lists are the same,

```
assert len(A) == len(B) == len(C)
for a, b, c in zip(A, B, C):
    print a, b, c    # replace with file write
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at using `zip`.  With `zip` you get a list of tuples, the tuples being the ith item of each list.  As a bonus, the list of tuples is truncated to the shortest list of the three:

```
myComboList = zip(A, B, C)
```

Then you can always write the things in the order you'd like them without fear that one list may be shorter/longer than any of the others.

Comment: It works but now how can I print it without ['u, because in a list,([u' added before the element. Can I use a for loop on this zip list?

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are long, itertools.izip() will probably be your friend. File object .writelines() can consume the list, or you can insert a yield construct in between to do the formatting.

```
def format(seq):
  for l in seq:
    yield "%s %s %s" % l
f.writelines(format(itertools.izip(A, B, C)))
```

Comment: Poor idea IMO to create a specific function ``format()`` while there's a built-in one. But +1 to associate `writelines()` and ``itertools.izip()``

Comment: Ah, format() was backported to 2.6; I hadn't noticed. Then eyquem below has the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Taking idea of `itertools.izip()` from **Bittrance** ,

plus the fact that a built-in function `format()` already exists :

```
import itertools

A = ['arez','hgjkhg','jhdfg','uhireug']
B = ['aaa','bbb','cccc','ddd']
C = ['XXXX','YYYY','ZZZZ','WWWWW']

with open('zorgl.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines("[{0}] [{1}] [{2}]\n".format(*tu)
                 for tu in itertools.izip(A, B, C))
```

result in the file

```
[arez] [aaa] [XXXX]
[hgjkhg] [bbb] [YYYY]
[jhdfg] [cccc] [ZZZZ]
[uhireug] [ddd] [WWWWW]
```

And a revelation happened to me:

I had never realized that `writelines()` writes a sequence of strings, which can be an iterable, while `write()` writes only one string

Until now I was doing this kind of thing:

```
f.write('\n'.join(sequentia))
```

to write in a file.

But `'\n'.join(sequentia)` is an object that is created before being written in one time. I believe.

Comparatively, `writelines()` can receive an iterable, then the writing of lines can be done one line at a time. This allows to write progressively a big quantity of data in a file, while it could be harder to write the total amount of data in only one chunk at one time.

Am I right ?

The only little defect of `writelines()` is that it writes the strings as they are, without adding a newline.

So `writelines(sequentz)` writes the same as `write(''.join(sequentz))` . Only `write('\n'.join(sequentz))` adds a newline between elements